# How to access user data in Azure Mobile App services (.Net backend)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on an app using Azure's Mobile App services (as opposed to Azure Mobile Services). I've successfully implemented the single sign-on with FB (mentioned here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication-preview/), but now that I can log in I can't figure out how to access the user information on the backend (such as basic user information and access tokens).

Could someone please provide an example or point me to a tutorial explaining how to access this data?

Comment: have you tried look for facebook sdk example ? you need to take the fb auth token and query fb server from your backend.

Comment: I can do this from the client, no problem, but I want to be able to do it from the server using Mobile Apps built-in OAuth setup.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following tutorial blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/16/enhanced-users-feature-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx - also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx

This is written a while ago, and uses the NodeJS backend, but you should be able to translate this to .NET as the same basic information exists - you use GetIdentities() to get the facebook token, then use the Facebook REST interface or the SDK (http://facebooksdk.net/) to get the rest of the information you need.

The basic piece of information you need is to use the GetIdentities() call to get your

Comment: I've been through that one. While there is a User object exposed by APIServices, it starts out null and I've no idea how to populate it.